# how to access the property from array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

i use angularjs to fetch the property on an array in console.log but when i try to access i am not able to get the property 'name' in array.From this i have to access the name property.

```
angular.module('ob3App.lead')
    .controller('LeadProductCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
        console.log('yjuhw');
        $scope.products=[];

    $scope.namegetfunction = function(){

        $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Product?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.lent = response.data[0].name;
            console.log($scope.lent);
            alert('hi');
        })
        .error(function(response){
            alert('error');
        }); 
    };
    $scope.namegetfunction();

 }]);
```

the following or my ionic ui view i need to view all the names in list but i am not able to view it.

```
 <ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive flat">
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="back()"><i class="ion-arrow-left-c"> </i></button>
        <h1 class="title">Products</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>

        <ul class="list">
            <li class="item"  ui-sref="leadProduct" ng-repate="i in products">
             {i}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Where is the property 'name'?

Comment: there are name properties in it so i have removed some

Comment: if you see down there is name:"sai" like this i need to console the name of all 6 array name property in list

Comment: Please update the JSON/ARRAY containing this property

Comment: you see the console.log(response);

Comment: that out put is what i have given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the response from API already have a "response" name object and you are trying to reach the json path wrong, here's the right route response.response.data[0].name

I just did a quick demo using the following code.

```
$http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Product?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
.success(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    $scope.lent = json.response.data;
    console.log($scope.lent.length);

    $scope.lent.forEach(function(item){
      console.log(item.name);
      $scope.products.push(item);
    })

    console.log($scope.products);

})
.error(function(json){
    alert('error');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/q1BqVM?p=preview

Comment: one doubt the name that i have displayed in the in console.log is pushed to array am i correct

Comment: I'm pushing the entire object, so i just access to the name using "item.name" or you can access to item.client or what ever. if you just want the name, on the products array you should push item.name instead of item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435792/how-to-view-the-data-from-array-in-list-using-ionic-and-angularjs

Comment: please check the above link

Comment: please can you help me solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452335/how-to-access-the-property-from-particular-object-in-angularjs/34452479#34452479

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
response.data.forEach(function(oneObj, key) {
    console.log(oneObj['name'])
})
```

or

```
response.data.forEach(function(oneObj, key) {
    console.log(oneObj.name)
})
```

Comment: i am getting an error like TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Please give me structure of 'data'

Comment: gopi.mohan16@gmail.com plese come on hang out

Comment: data: Array[6]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object

Comment: in each obect there is a property called name i am trying to access that name property

Comment: i dont have 20 reputation to join

Comment: Sorry friend I don't have access to hangout currently.I am office

Comment: oh k no issues but did you understand my requirement

Comment: yes,but please post json structure of your array.try to console response and response.data and check the which variable you get undefined

Comment: or give me screenshot by expanding data upto '-data'

Comment: i get console.log(response) as success and console.log(response.data) as undefined

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/34435792/…

Comment: please can you help me solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452335/how-to-access-the-property-from-particular-object-in-angularjs/34452479#34452479